# Can we download SoundCloud data?

Tags: soundcloud

I am planning to do a data analysis of the moods in music tracks uploaded to SoundCloud and the metadata associated with those tracks to study how the mood in the content of music have an effect on the comments posted to it.

Is there any way I can download tracks with varying moods which are downloadable from SoundCloud and also the comments and other meta data associated with them?

If there are existing SoundCloud based datasets made available specifically for data mining can anyone point me to them too?

Comment: For some tracks, yes - you can download them as an MP3 without even logging in. I suspect this is a flag the publisher can switch on and off, and depends on the licensing situation for each track. For others, you _might_ be able to download them, since the Flash application can also do so, but it might be encrypted or obfuscated. Also, have you checked if there is an API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a boolean in the Soundcloud API called `downloadable` which returns true if the artist has made a downloadable version available.  Then you could call the `download_url` function to get the downloadable file.  Alternatively, you could also call `stream_url` which returns the 128kbps streaming file, but I doubt that has the metadata/info you're looking for (but could be a backup in case `downloadable` returns false).

This page in the Soundcloud API should help get you started:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks